# Lightning FlexiPage fails to propagate properties from Aura component to embeded Lightning Web Component on re-renderings

Tags: lightning-web-components

Aura component with an embedded lightning web component with parameters, the parameters are not passed to the embedded component on subsequent renderings

**Setup:**
Service console
Create a Lightning Record Page with an Aura component
The aura component should contain an attribute:
    
The aura component should contain a Lightning Web Component

Within a wire method write the output of the property to the console
Override the new Case action with the Aura component above

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Navigate to Case List view
- Click New
- F12 in Chrome to bring up developer tools

*works correctly, this.isCreate has been populated correctly*

- close the tab
- and click New a second time

*does not work correctly, note that this time this.isCreate is undefined*

Comment: Found a workaround to Lightning Web Component wire service persistence issue when embedded in an Aura component.  Rather than use a function with the wire service, use a property.